# character count using Javascript is not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

This is what I am using for counting characters in textarea. Which is working fine in desktop devices. But where as in mobile devices there was some counting errors. For example in some devices it was taking up to 301 characters and after that backspace is not working.

```
function checkcharcount(e, eleid)
  {
        var max = 300;
        var val = document.getElementById(eleid).value;
        document.getElementById("cccount").innerText = val.length;

        if (e.which < 0x20) {
            // e.which < 0x20, then it's not a printable character
            // e.which === 0 - Not a character
            return;     // Do nothing
        }
        if (document.getElementById(eleid).value.length == max) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else if (document.getElementById(eleid).value.length > max) {
            // Maximum exceeded
            document.getElementById(eleid).value = document.getElementById(eleid).value.substring(0, max);
        }
        document.getElementById("cccount").innerText = val.length;
  }
```

Any suggestions highly appreciated. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: why don't you use `maxlength` attribute?

Comment: Yes I can use that. But I am looking for javascript/ Jquery based solution.